# can anybody help me to solve diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

I tried to solve this equation and it seems to be very tough
$(xy)^{x}={(\frac{y}{x})}^y$
can anybody help me with this equation?

I tried to rewrite the equation using logarithms but it did not work. I think there must be a substituition but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you tried to solve it, what did you try? The reason you're getting downvotes is because your question doesn't address what you've tried on your own.

Comment: I tried to rewrite the equation using logarithms but it did not work. I think there must be a substituition but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I have moved your comment to the main question, as from the previous body of question, anyone would think that you have done nothing, and in turn would lead to downvotes.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: @Servaes The title says "Diophantine Equation." Probably yes.

Comment: What is the $e$?  Is it an integer?  Euler's constant?  In the second case, the right is rational, the left is not.

Comment: there is no e, it was a typo, i already edited it

Comment: @RossMillikan Euler's constant is $0.57721\ldots$, isn't it?

Comment: no, as far as i know e - base of the natural logarithm and equals to 2.718...

Comment: i found one solution for x=3 and y=9 but cant figure out about how to extend it

Comment: $x=y=1$ also works...

Comment: @JaideepKhare I'd just like it to be explicit in the question, as some diophantine problems ask for rational solutions.

Comment: Taking logs is rarely a good idea for Diophantine equations.  They lose the granularity of the naturals, as $\log 2.1$ is not easy to tell from $\log 2$.  Factoring and divisibility are often more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The left side is an integer, so the right must be as well.  We can write $y=kx$ and the equation becomes $$(kx^2)^x=k^{kx}\\kx^2=k^k\\x^2=k^{k-1}$$ so $k$ must be odd.  We can take $k$ to be any odd positive integer and find both $x$ and $y$ from that.
$$x=k^{\left(\frac {k-1}2 \right)}\\y=k^{\left(\frac {k+1}2 \right)}$$